# archiving log per day and when size reached

Tags: java, logback

in the example below, each time i restart the server it will create a log compressed under an archived directory.

How can i specify that the log file will be archived only once per day and when the size of the log file is superior than the value specified in maxFileSize

```
<appender name="SERVICE-PROVIDER-LOG" class="ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.RollingFileAppender">
    <file>${LOG_HOME}/log/test.log</file>

    <rollingPolicy class="ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.TimeBasedRollingPolicy">
        <!-- We are rolling over daily -->
        <fileNamePattern>${LOG_HOME}/log/archived/test-%d{yyyy-MM-dd}.%i.log.gz
        </fileNamePattern>
        <timeBasedFileNamingAndTriggeringPolicy class="ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.SizeAndTimeBasedFNATP">
            <maxFileSize>50MB</maxFileSize>
        </timeBasedFileNamingAndTriggeringPolicy>
        <!-- keep 10 days' worth of history capped at 1GB total size -->
        <maxHistory>10</maxHistory>
        <totalSizeCap>1GB</totalSizeCap>
    </rollingPolicy>

    <encoder class="ch.qos.logback.classic.encoder.PatternLayoutEncoder">
        <Pattern>%d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSS} [%-5.5p] [%thread] [%-20.20C:%-5.5L] %msg%n</Pattern>
    </encoder>
</appender>
```

Answer (score 0):

I can't reproduce your problem. I've created a minimal runtime with your configuration:

https://github.com/riskop/logback_timeandsizebased_archived_oldstyle.git

This is my result with that:

```
riskop@riskop:~/git$ git clone https://github.com/riskop/logback_timeandsizebased_archived_oldstyle.git
Cloning into 'logback_timeandsizebased_archived_oldstyle'...
remote: Counting objects: 20, done.
remote: Compressing objects: 100% (10/10), done.
remote: Total 20 (delta 2), reused 17 (delta 2), pack-reused 0
Unpacking objects: 100% (20/20), done.
Checking connectivity... done.
riskop@riskop:~/git$ cd logback_timeandsizebased_archived_oldstyle/
riskop@riskop:~/git/logback_timeandsizebased_archived_oldstyle$ mvn -q -DLOG_HOME=loghome test

-------------------------------------------------------
 T E S T S
-------------------------------------------------------
Running pack.TestStart
11:01:18,720 |-INFO in ch.qos.logback.classic.LoggerContext[default] - Could NOT find resource [logback-test.xml]
11:01:18,720 |-INFO in ch.qos.logback.classic.LoggerContext[default] - Could NOT find resource [logback.groovy]
11:01:18,720 |-INFO in ch.qos.logback.classic.LoggerContext[default] - Found resource [logback.xml] at [file:/home/riskop/git/logback_timeandsizebased_archived_oldstyle/target/test-classes/logback.xml]
11:01:18,753 |-INFO in ch.qos.logback.classic.joran.action.ConfigurationAction - debug attribute not set
11:01:18,754 |-INFO in ch.qos.logback.core.joran.action.AppenderAction - About to instantiate appender of type [ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.RollingFileAppender]
11:01:18,758 |-INFO in ch.qos.logback.core.joran.action.AppenderAction - Naming appender as [SERVICE-PROVIDER-LOG]
11:01:18,769 |-INFO in c.q.l.core.rolling.TimeBasedRollingPolicy@1006485584 - setting totalSizeCap to 1 GB
11:01:18,790 |-INFO in c.q.l.core.rolling.TimeBasedRollingPolicy@1006485584 - Will use gz compression
11:01:18,791 |-INFO in c.q.l.core.rolling.TimeBasedRollingPolicy@1006485584 - Will use the pattern loghome/log/archived/test-%d{yyyy-MM-dd}.%i.log for the active file
11:01:18,793 |-INFO in ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.SizeAndTimeBasedFNATP@1bce4f0a - The date pattern is 'yyyy-MM-dd' from file name pattern 'loghome/log/archived/test-%d{yyyy-MM-dd}.%i.log.gz'.
11:01:18,793 |-INFO in ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.SizeAndTimeBasedFNATP@1bce4f0a - Roll-over at midnight.
11:01:18,794 |-INFO in ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.SizeAndTimeBasedFNATP@1bce4f0a - Setting initial period to Tue Mar 13 11:01:18 CET 2018
11:01:18,795 |-WARN in ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.SizeAndTimeBasedFNATP@1bce4f0a - SizeAndTimeBasedFNATP is deprecated. Use SizeAndTimeBasedRollingPolicy instead
11:01:18,795 |-WARN in ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.SizeAndTimeBasedFNATP@1bce4f0a - For more information see http://logback.qos.ch/manual/appenders.html#SizeAndTimeBasedRollingPolicy
11:01:18,806 |-INFO in ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.RollingFileAppender[SERVICE-PROVIDER-LOG] - Active log file name: loghome/log/test.log
11:01:18,806 |-INFO in ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.RollingFileAppender[SERVICE-PROVIDER-LOG] - File property is set to [loghome/log/test.log]
11:01:18,806 |-INFO in ch.qos.logback.classic.joran.action.RootLoggerAction - Setting level of ROOT logger to INFO
11:01:18,807 |-INFO in ch.qos.logback.core.joran.action.AppenderRefAction - Attaching appender named [SERVICE-PROVIDER-LOG] to Logger[ROOT]
11:01:18,807 |-INFO in ch.qos.logback.classic.joran.action.ConfigurationAction - End of configuration.
11:01:18,807 |-INFO in ch.qos.logback.classic.joran.JoranConfigurator@5e3a8624 - Registering current configuration as safe fallback point

Tests run: 1, Failures: 0, Errors: 0, Skipped: 0, Time elapsed: 1.544 sec - in pack.TestStart

Results :

Tests run: 1, Failures: 0, Errors: 0, Skipped: 0

riskop@riskop:~/git/logback_timeandsizebased_archived_oldstyle$ ls -l loghome/log/
total 1052
-rw-rw-r-- 1 riskop riskop 1074890 márc  13 11:01 test.log
riskop@riskop:~/git/logback_timeandsizebased_archived_oldstyle$ mvn -q -DLOG_HOME=loghome test

-------------------------------------------------------
 T E S T S
-------------------------------------------------------
Running pack.TestStart
11:01:27,654 |-INFO in ch.qos.logback.classic.LoggerContext[default] - Could NOT find resource [logback-test.xml]
11:01:27,655 |-INFO in ch.qos.logback.classic.LoggerContext[default] - Could NOT find resource [logback.groovy]
11:01:27,655 |-INFO in ch.qos.logback.classic.LoggerContext[default] - Found resource [logback.xml] at [file:/home/riskop/git/logback_timeandsizebased_archived_oldstyle/target/test-classes/logback.xml]
11:01:27,698 |-INFO in ch.qos.logback.classic.joran.action.ConfigurationAction - debug attribute not set
11:01:27,699 |-INFO in ch.qos.logback.core.joran.action.AppenderAction - About to instantiate appender of type [ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.RollingFileAppender]
11:01:27,705 |-INFO in ch.qos.logback.core.joran.action.AppenderAction - Naming appender as [SERVICE-PROVIDER-LOG]
11:01:27,722 |-INFO in c.q.l.core.rolling.TimeBasedRollingPolicy@1006485584 - setting totalSizeCap to 1 GB
11:01:27,745 |-INFO in c.q.l.core.rolling.TimeBasedRollingPolicy@1006485584 - Will use gz compression
11:01:27,747 |-INFO in c.q.l.core.rolling.TimeBasedRollingPolicy@1006485584 - Will use the pattern loghome/log/archived/test-%d{yyyy-MM-dd}.%i.log for the active file
11:01:27,749 |-INFO in ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.SizeAndTimeBasedFNATP@1bce4f0a - The date pattern is 'yyyy-MM-dd' from file name pattern 'loghome/log/archived/test-%d{yyyy-MM-dd}.%i.log.gz'.
11:01:27,749 |-INFO in ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.SizeAndTimeBasedFNATP@1bce4f0a - Roll-over at midnight.
11:01:27,751 |-INFO in ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.SizeAndTimeBasedFNATP@1bce4f0a - Setting initial period to Tue Mar 13 11:01:20 CET 2018
11:01:27,752 |-WARN in ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.SizeAndTimeBasedFNATP@1bce4f0a - SizeAndTimeBasedFNATP is deprecated. Use SizeAndTimeBasedRollingPolicy instead
11:01:27,752 |-WARN in ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.SizeAndTimeBasedFNATP@1bce4f0a - For more information see http://logback.qos.ch/manual/appenders.html#SizeAndTimeBasedRollingPolicy
11:01:27,763 |-INFO in ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.RollingFileAppender[SERVICE-PROVIDER-LOG] - Active log file name: loghome/log/test.log
11:01:27,763 |-INFO in ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.RollingFileAppender[SERVICE-PROVIDER-LOG] - File property is set to [loghome/log/test.log]
11:01:27,764 |-INFO in ch.qos.logback.classic.joran.action.RootLoggerAction - Setting level of ROOT logger to INFO
11:01:27,764 |-INFO in ch.qos.logback.core.joran.action.AppenderRefAction - Attaching appender named [SERVICE-PROVIDER-LOG] to Logger[ROOT]
11:01:27,765 |-INFO in ch.qos.logback.classic.joran.action.ConfigurationAction - End of configuration.
11:01:27,765 |-INFO in ch.qos.logback.classic.joran.JoranConfigurator@5e3a8624 - Registering current configuration as safe fallback point

Tests run: 1, Failures: 0, Errors: 0, Skipped: 0, Time elapsed: 1.568 sec - in pack.TestStart

Results :

Tests run: 1, Failures: 0, Errors: 0, Skipped: 0

riskop@riskop:~/git/logback_timeandsizebased_archived_oldstyle$ ls -l loghome/log/
total 2100
-rw-rw-r-- 1 riskop riskop 2149780 márc  13 11:01 test.log
```

Log entries are appended to test.log as you can see (test.log length is about 1M after the first run. After the second run of the test test.log is 2M).

Note however, that your usage of SizeAndTimeBasedFNATP is deprecated.

Answer (score 0):

Which version of Logback are you using? If you are below Version 1.1.7, you should consider updating because this will enable you to use SizeAndTimeBasedRollingPolicy.

I had a similiar problem and the solution for me was to use the SizeAndTimeBasedRollingPolicy like so:

```
<appender name="SERVICE-PROVIDER-LOG" class="ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.RollingFileAppender">
    <rollingPolicy
        class="ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.SizeAndTimeBasedRollingPolicy">
        <fileNamePattern>
           ${LOG_HOME}/log/archived/test-%d{yyyy-MM-dd}.%i.log.gz
        </fileNamePattern>
        <maxFileSize>50MB</maxFileSize>
        <maxHistory>10</maxHistory>
        <totalSizeCap>1GB</totalSizeCap>
    </rollingPolicy>
    <encoder>
        <charset>UTF-8</charset>
        <Pattern>%d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSS} [%-5.5p] [%thread] [%-20.20C:%-5.5L] %msg%n</Pattern>
    </encoder>
</appender>
```

Hope this helps!